# Segmentation Fault with PHP5 on Solaris 10

Tags: apache-2.2, php, solaris

On a Solaris 10 server I installed Apache2 (v2.2.20), PHP5 (v5.2.1), and all dependencies with packages from [1]: http://unixpackages.com (the new sunfreeware.com).

Now apache is running, and doesn't generate errors at startup. The probleme is when I ask the server with a browser I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

In logs, each time I ask the server I get this error :

```
child pid "PID" signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

It seems coming from PHP while there's no error when deactivate it in httpd.conf, but I can't find where.

[EDIT]

Using the last version of PHP available on unixpackages.com (v5.3.6) and forcing some library paths during install solved the problem.
It seems that older version don't works with Apache v2.2.20.

Thanks a lot for your answers even if they weren't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know how to comment, I'm going answer instead. I'm sorry for any inconveniences.

1. Make sure everything is updated, especially PHP.
2. If you're using PDO, keep it updated. Also try to switch from PDO_MYSQL to MYSQLI in the config/config.ini.php.
3. If none of the above worked, disable any plugins/extensions.

Source for the steps above can be found [here](http://piwik.org/faq/troubleshooting/#faq_131)

Also, there are similar questions on Serverfault. You might be able to acquire more information by using GDB, there are posts about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-3580-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-l).

In addition, there seems to be many discussions regarding the segfault error you received on other sites. I found a bunch using google, finding them yourself shouldn't prove to be so much of a challange.

Answer (score 0):

[Enable core dumps](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/manage_core_dump.html#ManageProcess). Use pstack on the core to show the stack trace. Edit your question and add the stack trace.